# AngularJS 1.6 $injector:modulerr Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've added some services to my application (which was working fine before-hand) and now it will not load and give me the error `$injector:modulerr`

My app looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module("HtJobPortal", ["LocalStorageModule"]);
var serviceBase = "http://autherserverlink/";
var resourceBase = "http://resourceserverlink/";
(function () {
   "use strict";    
    app.constant("ngAuthSettings", {
        apiServiceBaseUri: serviceBase,
        apiResourceBaseUri: resourceBase,
        clientId: "TMS_Portal"
    });
    app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptorService");
    });
    app.run(["authService", function (authService) {
        authService.fillAuthData();
    }]);
})();
```

And the Services I have declared are:

```
<!-- JS Scripts -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Application Directive -->
<script src="Scripts/controllers/app.js"></script>

<!-- Services -->
<script src="Scripts/services/authService.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/services/authInterceptorService.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/services/tokensManagerService.js"></script>
```

I've had a look around other similar errors and seen that this error can be caused by a number of things so I'm just not really sure how to narrow this down? So I assumed the best place would be start with the declarations and the app itself?

Comment: Where does the `LocalStorageModule` come from? I don't see it in the list of scrips.

Comment: That fixed it thanks - must have missed that one off - if you want to pop that in as the answer for others then I'll mark it as correct if you like?

Comment: No problem, that happens to everyone. I've included it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to include the script containing the `LocalStorageModule`, which causes Angular to throw the `$injector:modulerr`.

Simply include the missing scripts and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please load LocalStorageModule's library or relevant js file before your app in html..